# Disconnect Specific Users From PostgreSQL Database

Tags: database, postgresql, dbeaver

I need to disconnect several former team members from our postgres database. I have seen several solutions which talk about disconnecting all users from the database. However, it would be preferrable if we didn't have to disconnect all users because that would mean disconnecting the current team members too. So my question is, how do I disconnet specific users who are connected to our postgres database?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where usename in ('specific','user','name');
```